# LogonUser() fails for Azure AD user when username is in UPN format even when password is correct

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msdn

This is my code to check if the password entered by user is correct.
My user is an AzureAD user logged in to a windows 10 Azure AD joined machine.

---

```
if (LogonUser(upn., NULL, pwd, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token) != 0)
```

---

LogonUser fails with error 1326 . Invalid username or password.
But the same in Domain\username format works correctly.

What do I do to get it working when username is in UPN format.

Comment: Interesting... I know the docs say the lpszDomain parameter needs to be NULL for UPN format. For grins, have you tried using "AzureAD" for it?

Comment: yes it works on adding AzureAD.  but doubtful if I should do it because document says use null while using upn.

Comment: That API is pretty old. Probably they haven't updated the documentation. The AzureAD joining is relatively new...certainly a lot newer than when that documentation was originally written. But, I understand the trepidation about calling it that way when the docs say not to. I just thought the AzureAD adds another level of complexity and the only way to resolve it in that API was to include the AzureAD domain. Wish Raymond would chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Joseph Willcoxson

setting the domain field to "AzureAD" fixed the issue. Hope microsoft updates the document soon.